# How to dynamically name variables in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, variables, dynamic-variables

I'm very new and I was practicing with react.

The TL;DR of this post is that I want to dynamically create some variables in react and I can't.

I'm creating a web page of a store with React. So in order to do the home page where the products are displayed, I wrote a `Product` component that takes some properties like this

```
import React from 'react'


function Product({id,title,image,image_description,price,description}) {
    return (
        <div >
            <div >
                <p>{title}</p>
                <b>{price}$</b>
                <img src={image} alt={image_description}/>
                <p>{description}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Product
```

Then I created a `ProductDataComponent` where I created an array that contains some objects with those properties

```
var productData = [
// 0
    {
        id : 10,
        title: 'Jugo de Naranja', 
        image: 'urlOfImage.com', 
        image_description: 'Juguito de naranja' , 
        price: 100, 
        description: 'Un rico jugo de naranja'  
    },
//1 
{
  etc
}
];


export default productData
```

Then I imported that component in the home component, and in order to make the code cleaner, I made some variables that takes one element of the array

```
import React from 'react'
import Product from './Product'
import './Home.css'
import productData from './ProductDataComponent'

var  p0 = productData[0]
var  p1 = productData[1]

function Home() {
    return (
        <div className='home'>
            <div className="home__container">
                <div className="home__row">
                    <Product id={p0.id} title= {p0.title} image={p0.image} image_description={p0.image_description} price={p0.price} description={p0.description}/>
                    <Product id={p2.id} title= {p2.title} image={p2.image} image_description={p2.image_description} price={p2.price} description={p2.description}/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Home
```

And to that point the code worked fine.

The problem is that I want to automate the making of variables process, so I don't have to write manually every time that I add a new object in the array of `productData`.

I searched a way to do it, and I found 2 ways. One with the `eval()` method that is evil and doesn't work.

And the other way is doing a for loop like this

```
var i 
for (let i = 0; i < productData.length; i++) {
    window['p'+i] = productData[i];
}
```

I tested this method in other page isolated in javascript, and it worked but when I put it in the home component in react, it doesn't work.

This is what the web page shows.

```
Failed to compile

src\Home.js
  Line 32:34:   'p0' is not defined  no-undef
  Line 32:49:   'p0' is not defined  no-undef
  Line 32:66:   'p0' is not defined  no-undef
  Line 32:95:   'p0' is not defined  no-undef
  Line 32:124:  'p0' is not defined  no-undef
  Line 32:147:  'p0' is not defined  no-undef
  Line 33:34:   'p1' is not defined  no-undef
  Line 33:49:   'p1' is not defined  no-undef
  Line 33:66:   'p1' is not defined  no-undef
  Line 33:95:   'p1' is not defined  no-undef
  Line 33:124:  'p1' is not defined  no-undef
  Line 33:147:  'p1' is not defined  no-undef
```

Is there something that I'm doing wrong?

Is there a way to dynamically name variables or automate the process?

PS: I'm not a native English speaker, so please forgive my grammar sins.

Comment: You seem to be solving the wrong problem, you should not store data in the window object. You can use `map` to dynamically create elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use map and return jsx:

```
const rednderedProduct =productData.map( (p)=> {return <Product id={p.id} title= {p.title} image={p.image} image_description={p.image_description} price={p.price} description={p.description}/> })
```

and then in return part of component:

```
return({rednderedProduct})
```

something like that...

Comment: Wow, so fast!! , your soultion worked. And the solution of MaartenDev also worked, but with this solution i can choose what element of the array i can display by puting '{renderedProduct[1]}' or  '{renderedProduct[2]}'. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be searching for a way to dynamically make react elements. This can be done using `map`. Checkout the following example:

```js
import productData from './ProductDataComponent'

function Home() {
    return (
        <div className='home'>
            <div className="home__container">
                <div className="home__row">
                    {productData.map(product => <Product id={product.id} title= {product.title} image={product.image} image_description={product.image_description} price={product.price} description={product.description}/>)}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Checkout the react docs: [Rendering multiple components](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#rendering-multiple-components)